# Why am I getting a "Cannot find module 'jsonLogic'" error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsonlogic

I've installed [JsonLogic](http://jsonlogic.com/) using [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/).

```sh
yarn add json-logic-js
```

When I attempt to implement a simple example:

```
import jsonLogic from 'jsonLogic';

jsonLogic.apply({ '==': [1, 1] });
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot find module 'jsonLogic'
```

Why can't Node find the JsonLogic module? And how do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing a nonexistent module. Import the `json-logic-js` module, not the nonexistent `jsonLogic` module. For example:

```
import jsonLogic from 'json-logic-js';

jsonLogic.apply({ '==': [1, 1] });
```